# red5 Install on Ubuntu 10.04? Problems with libslf4j

Tags: installation, classpath, red5, ubuntu-10.04

I've been trying for many days to get Red5 to install on Ubuntu 10.04. I finally managed to get red5.sh to stop hanging a few seconds in but now I'm getting the following error:

```
Setting default logging context: default
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:135)
 at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getContextSelector()Lch/qos/logback/classic/selector/ContextSelector;
 at org.red5.logging.Red5LoggerFactory.getLogger(Red5LoggerFactory.java:121)
 at org.red5.logging.Red5LoggerFactory.getLogger(Red5LoggerFactory.java:108)
 at org.red5.server.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
 ... 6 more
```

I suspected that this had to do with slf4j not being installed or on my classpath. I installed logback and libslf4j-java from aptitude and I see related files in my red5 lib directories. For example:

```
/usr/share/red5/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
/usr/share/red5/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-classic-0.9.26.jar
/usr/share/red5/lib/logback-core-0.9.26.jar
/usr/share/red5/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
/usr/share/red5/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
```

And I set my classpath to /usr/share/red5/lib/

Any ideas on where to proceed from here? There seem to be a lot of people having trouble getting 10.04 and red5 0.9 working together. I've tried red5-0.9.1.tar.gz and red5_0.9.0-RC1_all.deb. The libraries above should be all that are needed according to [Red5's documentation](http://www.red5.org/wiki/Documentation/Tutorials/LoggingSetup) and I got the latest version of each.

Answer (score 1):

Use this tutorial:
http://tumbledesign.com/how-to-install-red5-0-9-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/
It has been done for me.